# How to get the number of Facebook likes for a URL consistently?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a URL that can be expressed as HTTP and HTTPS (technically they're different URLs but there seems to be consensus that they're 'the same').

In this example the HTTP URL redirects to the HTTP one. This happens in many cases, but I'm using `facebook.com` as an example.

My aim is to get a "total comment and share count for `http://facebook.com` or `https://facebook.com`".

Querying using the HTTP URL `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/http://facebook.com?access_token=XXXX` gives us:

```
  {
    og_object: {
      id: "10151063484068358",
      title: "Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More",
      type: "website",
      updated_time: "2016-08-31T14:49:01+0000"
    },
    share: {
      comment_count: 5252,
      share_count: 115724962
    },
    id: "http://facebook.com"
  }
```

And using HTTPS, `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/https://facebook.com?access_token=XXXX`:

```
  {
    og_object: {
      id: "10151063484068358",
      title: "Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More",
      type: "website",
      updated_time: "2016-08-31T14:49:41+0000"
    },
    share: {
      comment_count: 1348,
      share_count: 115725362
    },
    id: "https://facebook.com"
  }
```

Using the `og_object.id`, if I query `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/10151063484068358/likes?summary=true&access_token=XXXX` I get:

```
{
  summary: {
    total_count: 5890439,
    can_like: false,
    has_liked: false
  }
}
```

Which is entirely different again.

And using the `engagement` field 
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/10151063484068358?fields=engagement&access_token=XXXX`

```
{
  engagement: {
    count: 115740062,
    social_sentence: "115M people like this."
  },
  id: "10151063484068358"
}
```

I get 115740062, which a different number *again*, but at least close to the above (caches may be updated on different schedules).

As a side note, the `engagement` and `likes` both claim to represent likes, but in another example, they disagree:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/https://www.co-operativebank.co.uk/?access_token=XXXX` gives 910 likes:

```
{
  og_object: {
    id: "10150337668163877",
    description: "The Co-operative Bank provides personal banking services including current accounts, credit cards, online and mobile banking, personal loans, savings and more",
    title: "Personal banking | Online banking | Co-op Bank",
    type: "website",
    updated_time: "2016-08-31T14:07:30+0000"
  },
  share: {
    comment_count: 0,
    share_count: 910
  },
  id: "https://www.co-operativebank.co.uk/"
}
```

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/10150337668163877?fields=engagement&access_token=XXXX` gives the same 910 likes

```
{
  engagement: {
    count: 910,
    social_sentence: "910 people like this."
  },
  id: "10150337668163877"
}
```

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/10150337668163877/likes?summary=true&access_token=XXXX` gives zero likes.

```
{
  data: [ ],
  summary: {
    total_count: 0,
    can_like: false,
    has_liked: false
  }
}
```

I'm caught between four different numbers and I only want one!

Observations:

- We get the same OpenGraph ID of `10151063484068358`, which I believe is caused by one URL redirecting to the other.
- We get different counts for the two URLs, so they are treated differently for share counts.
- HTTPS comments are lower than HTTP comments
- HTTPS shares are higher than HTTP shares
- The numbers 115724962 and 115725362 are too close to be independent but coincidentally similar counts.

I'm struggling to find anything consistent here.

Is it possible to get a headline figure for "total comment and share count for `http://facebook.com` or `https://facebook.com`?

Or is it possible to somehow use the `og_object.id` of `10151063484068358` to get a total count?

Comment: i'm having the same problem! did you get anywhere on this?

Comment: Sorry no. If you do get any further, an answer would be very welcome!