# What's the canonical URL for a Facebook Open Graph object when one URL redirects to another?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The URL `http://doi.org/10.5555/12345678` redirects to `http://psychoceramics.labs.crossref.org/10.5555-12345678.html`.

The Facebook Graph API considers them to be the same (they have the same ID).

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/http://doi.org/10.5555/12345678?access_token=XXXX

```
{
  og_object: {
    id: "10150995451832648",
    title: "Toward a Unified Theory of High-Energy Metaphysics: Silly String Theory",
    type: "website",
    updated_time: "2016-08-25T01:23:00+0000"
  },
  share: {
    comment_count: 0,
    share_count: 3
  },
  id: "http://doi.org/10.5555/12345678"
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/http://psychoceramics.labs.crossref.org/10.5555-12345678.html?access_token=XXXX

```
{
  og_object: {
    id: "10150995451832648",
    title: "Toward a Unified Theory of High-Energy Metaphysics: Silly String Theory",
    type: "website",
    updated_time: "2016-08-25T01:23:00+0000"
  },
  share: {
    comment_count: 0,
    share_count: 3
  },
  id: "http://psychoceramics.labs.crossref.org/10.5555-12345678.html"
}
```

Is there any way to find what Facebook considers to the canonical URL of the two?

Using introspection (i.e. passing `metadata=1`) doesn't seem to offer anything relevant.

Comment: There is not. And why would you want that?

Comment: Mostly because I'm trying to work out how to get the 'like' statistics for a set of URLs redirect pairs, and sometimes I know the redirect URL and sometimes I know the redirected. Also, the numbers from the FB API are inconsistent. I thought if I could find what FB considers to be the canonical one of the pair I might have better results. This is part of a wider question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254069/how-to-get-the-number-of-facebook-likes-for-a-url-consistently , but I thought I'd break it down.

Comment: (Also since I asked that question a bug report has been confirmed, although this isn't directly related to this specific question https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/545476068973925/ )